# Issue with nested soql query

Tags: soql

can anyone could have a look and let me know what is wrong with this query?

```
List projects = [SELECT id, Number_of_Assignments__c, Number_of_billable_assignments__c 
                   FROM Project__c 
                  WHERE id IN (SELECT Project__r.id, isActive__c 
                                 FROM Assignment__c WHERE isActive__c = true)];
```

It throws this error

"unexpected token: ,"

Project__c Master, Assignment__c Child

I will be very grateful for your assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two things to correct here:

1. It's not legal to have an untyped `List`. You need a `List<Project__c> projects`.
2. You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) traverse a relationship in your sub-select. Just do `WHERE Id IN (SELECT Project__c ...)`, i.e., use the relationship field directly as your Id column.

The documentation on this is at [Semi-Joins and Anti-Joins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin). There's a lot of power and some interesting facets/restrictions for this type of query.